# Refreshing Table View Rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, reload

I have a `UISegmentedControl` that changes the data in the table view.

```
[self.mySexyTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:updatedPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

Let's say that I display 5 rows for tab one, 2 rows for tab two. When the second tab is clicked the first two rows get new values but the old data from tab one for rows 3 to 5 remains. How can I clear them out ?

Comment: I'm assuming you're working in object-c on the iPhone. Please add those tags. Also, are you saything that you have a UITabViewController with 1 tableview per tab? Also, for readability, highlight your code and then hit the code format button so that it will appear properly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick sample code to check out: [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/index.html)

On topic, here is one of the sweetest provided methods:

```
// If I want to delete the next 3 cells after the one you click
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSMutableArray* indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (int i = indexPath.row + 1; i < indexPath.row + 4; i++)
  {
    [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
  }

  [tableView beginUpdates];
  [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
  [tableView endUpdates];
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

I ran into this problem, if I understand you properly, that updating doesn't remove cells. So just remove them and *then* call update.  Good luck!

Comment: @A-Live I realize it's doing some tricky things; anything in particular you're calling out?

Comment: It doesn't do anything, the initial value is matching the final value. There should also be a validation of the indexes before or inside of the loop to prevent going out of bounds.

Comment: I see what you're saying; admittedly, there are many things wrong with this code. I don't think I wrote it, but I certainly may have edited it. I've made a reasonable change to the loop and left the other needs as an excerise to the reader.